# how to set a cookie for unlimited expiration with a VisualBasic2010 web app

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

response.Cookies( SOFTWARE_PROGRAM_NAME).Expires = datetime.now.adddays(365*10)

this sets expiration for 10 years.

Anyway to set it for unlimited?

Comment: 10 years not enough for you? Most hardware dies long before it reaches that age.

Comment: Correct.
It seems I was being unreasonably perfectionistic.
(There's a Vulcan back somewhere in the family tree.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Cookies were intended to store temporary state information, like a token that identifies a shopping cart or user authentication session. User's can of course easily delete your cookie by clearing their browser cache anyway. If you want a cookie that lasts forever, you are never going to get it, and its not what cookies are for. If you want to store user-based information permanently, consider storing it in your database or other server side storage.

From [RFC2109](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2109/rfc2109):

There are, of course, many different potential contexts and thus many    different potential types of session.  The designers' paradigm for    sessions created by the exchange of cookies has these key attributes:

1. Each session has a beginning and an end.
2. Each session is relatively short-lived.
3. Either the user agent or the origin server may terminate a session.
4. The session is implicit in the exchange of state information.

I.e. cookies must expire because each session has a beginning and an end.

Comment: Thanks -- that is the correct perspective.

It's for storing the hide/show state of various page helps.
For now, I'll use cookies because I don't have development time to do a database.  When the site gets that successful, I'll hire someone to do that.

Comment: This is not answering the question